# Best practice for ensuring non-colliiding random backoff for distributed applications (k8s)

Tags: c#, .net, distributed-computing

So, we have a distributed application (kubernetes) and sometimes multiple instances are trying to update the same data in the database using optimistic concurrency. Only one succeeds, and the rest should retry.

To avoid collisions (remaining pods retrying at the exact same time), we want to add a random delay between retries. Here is where things get interesting. How do we ensure that most of the time these independent applications apply a different amount of delay?

I do not understand what calling `new Random()` without a seed entails. I understand that it will use some internal seed which is not based on current time (since .NET Core). That's good, because that implementation would result in collisions since the root of the problem is simultaneous attempts in the first time (same  or very similar current time when Random is instantiated). But where does the seed come from then?

I am concerned that in the context of using docker images (based on Alpine Linux) there might not be too much randomness in whatever unamanged code `new Random()` uses to seed itself. But I cannot figure out exactly where the seed comes from, nor do I have a good idea for a custom seed.

So my questions are two:

1. Is the default constructor on Random enough to ensure a high probability of avoiding collisions? Please explain/prove why.
2. If not, what is the best practice in such cases?

Comment: _"high probability"_ - how high do you consider "high"? And also "best practice" questions tend to get closed for being a) too broad and b) mostly opinionated. But to give you starter anyway: Why don't you start with the simplest possible implementation and see if that is enough? I am sure you _will_ do stress-tests, don't you? Now if you find that Random isn't Radnom enough for you, there are its cryptographic counterparts, which surely will be random enough.

Comment: I would be happy with 90% probability of avoiding collisions. We intend to stress test solutions, but I would like to understand what we are trying rather than throwing whatever at the wall without understanding why and how it should work and seeing what sticks.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but on what dotnet version are you? Asking, because: [the remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-random-ctor) of this docu suggests that the parameterless contructor of `Random` may indeed be sufficient, given you are on .Net Core. So, if so, _I_ would give that a try, because it would be the simplest implementation you can test fairly quickly. If that still falls short, you can look for different alternatives.

Comment: ... for example [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-8.0)

Comment: We're on .NET 7 currently. It just bugs the heck out of me that I'm using something I don't understand as well as I'd like to, but I guess that's what tests are for.

Comment: "Probieren geht über studieren" ... you can theorize all you want. In the end,  reality will show you what's right.

Comment: So this approach is random enough in the scenario of a distributed k8s application. I still wish I understood how it would worked under the hood, where the entropy comes from, but we do see a uniform-ish distribution of random delays with the default constructor even in scale-up events which result in a lot of pods being created at nearly the same time.